# How can I optimize Mustache rendering speed when rendering 8000+ items?

Tags: performance, optimization, rendering, mustache

I'm trying to render a table so the template is pretty simple; the row template looks like this:

```
  <script type=\"text/mustache\" id=\"template-list-records\">
  {{#.}}
   <tr>
    <td>{{airport_code}}</td>
    <td>{{city_code}}</td>
    <td class=\"pull-right\">
     [<a href=\"result.mics?m_uid={{airport_code}}\" class=\"listlink\">details</a>]
    </td>
   </tr>
  {{/.}}
  </script>
```

The problem is that rendering speeds starts to slow down exponentially when rendering more than 1000 results (I'm guessing it slows down exponentially all the time :) but with 1000+ results is noticeable that rendering speed is not linear). Now, at 4000 results, the page loads in 2.3 seconds. At 7000 results, rendering time is 7.3 seconds, and rendering the full result set (around 8500 results) takes 10 seconds. Now, I don't need to speed it up faster than 8 seconds for full result load (since that's the amount of time that the old functionality took to render the page), that would be a bonus :), but I still need to shave 2 seconds. I've looked at the Timeline inspector, the time is spent on rendering; rendering starts after 2.5 seconds.

I'm guessing part of the problem could be my laptop (I have some graphic card issues), but still, I'm interested if there's a way to speed this up, e.g. precompile the table with 8500 rows and add/remove rows if needed (this really is an airport list table so the number doesn't change often, and when it does, it doesn't change by much).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New idea: why not render the page incrementally then? I imagine that 8500 rows is quite a lot of "pages" (certainly around 200 "pages" on a 1080p screen) so you could easily implement a continuous scrolling mechanism where you keep rendering data in small chunks as needed.

Say for starters you begin rendering the first 500 items (which is already a lot), then as the user starts scrolling and approaches around 80% of the total scroll size you render 200 extra rows. You keep doing this until you run out of rows to render.

In the case you have a requirement that says you need to have everything available at once (so that users can ctrl+F for example) you could still try rendering in chunks: instead of feeding your template with the entire data set, break it down in sets of 500 and call Mustache as many times as needed with these smaller sets. If it still clogs, add a small timeout between calls to improve the perceived responsiveness.

TBH, I re-read your question and most of your time seems to be spent on the browser trying to calculate your table layout, so these suggestions should work fine for your case. As a last resort you could try with CSS `table-layout: fixed;` which will greatly speed up your table rendering but will also in turn force you to manually define the column widths as the table will no longer dynamically adapt the column width based on its contents.

Comment: I have the CTRL+F requirement, otherwise I would implement our classic 50+ items paging. I'll try to break the rendering down into chunks and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried to implement this and in the process realised that the problem is not so much Mustache/Hogan, the problem seems to lie with Backbone.js. I'm doing the rendering in Backbone.View, I've extended the render method and that method takes time to exit/render so I'll have to look at Backbone.js optimization

Comment: In the end, I decided to just get 10 results and do paging. But I've also discovered the problem - my implementation of the parser. The correct implementation is parsing all results and concatenating them in memory, and only after that, outputting the result. My implementation rendered and appended each element (updated the DOM), which triggered a redraw.. around 8000 times :D It's funny now, but it wasn't when I was asking :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try alternate Mustache implementations like [Hogan](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)?

Your template is quite small so there's not much you will win by using the pre-compiled templates feature, but specially in the case of Hogan it is finely tuned to speed up the rendering algorithm as much as possible, so there's a chance that by simply using an alternate implementation than vanilla Mustache will already fix your problems.

Also, if you are not already on the latest version of Mustache.js you could try simply upgrading. Older versions (about 1.5 years old) had serious performance issues.

Comment: Mustache version doesn't make a difference, I've tried the rendering with the latest version and it's the same speed. I read about Hogan/Handlebars but hoped something could be done just with Mustache.

Comment: Hogan **is** "just Mustache", both the syntax and the interpretation of it stay true to the [Mustache spec](https://github.com/mustache/spec/), so unlike Handlebars there's no temptation to alienate your templates. You could even write a wrapper on top of Hogan to avoid updating all your code to use the new API, at least for testing purposes.

Comment: I'm going to try Hogan and open a new question for problems with Hogan.js :)

Comment: I've managed to parse with Hogan but I still get the same speed :(

Comment: gonna add another answer now that we determined the problem is in the amount of data and not the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

How do you add mustache-rendered HTML into your DOM?

Try add rendered code in one point instead of continuous inserting.

slow, many insertions:

```
for () {
  table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML + Mustache.render(row);
}
```

faster, 1 insert:

```
var buffer = '';
for () {
  buffer = buffer + Mustache.render(row);
}
table.innerHTML = buffer;
```

Comment: The problem was solved with a typeahed functionality, but I think the real problem was, as you mentioned, DOM insertion/rerendering.